# How set entire object in computed property VUEjs

Tags: vue.js

My problem is that I have a computed property with setter and getter like:

```
computed:{
        dataComputed:{
            get: function () {  return  this.dataProps},
            set: function (newValue) {
               //here my problem
                this.dataProps= Object.assign({}, newValue);
            }

        }
    },
```

but my problem is that I would assign entire object retrieved from ajax call like:

```
var vm = this;
axios.post('/route', { data:this.dataComputed})
   .then(function (response) {
      vm.dataComputed = response.data.newData;
   }).catch(function (error) {});
```

but in console i have this warning:

> Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten
>   whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or
>   computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated:
>   "dataProps"

How can I assign entire object retrieved from backend to computed object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the error message you have, it looks like `dataProps` is a property of your component and properties can't be mutated. Try assigning `Object.assign({}, newValue);` to a `data` variable and not a variable from `props`.

Comment: Hello, I don't know if the best way, I have resolved creating a data{  object:dataProps } and in computed:
get: function () {  return  this.object},
            set: function(newValue){
                this.object= newValue;
            }

Comment: Well, that's the way to do it ;-)